# jQuery .closest() not working after AJAX call?

Tags: jquery, ajax

I am trying to remove a div after an AJAX call but `.closest()` function doesn't seem to be working as expected. As I understand it climbs up until it finds a match.

```html
<div class="comments">
  <div class="commment">
    <p>
      <strong>admin</strong> - 2018-10-10 08:50:03
    </p>
    <p>az</p>
    <form id="deleteCommentForm" method="POST" action="http://127.0.0.1:8000/comments/30" accept-charset="UTF-8">
      <input name="_method" type="hidden" value="DELETE"><input name="_token" type="hidden" value="FmNpDb8bmwTLPgTYUuyGxsvAuluyskXVYs9p0rdu">
      <button type="submit" id="completed-task" class="fabutton" style="background: none; padding: 0px; border: none;">
        <i class="fas fa-trash-alt"></i>
      </button>
    </form>
    <hr>
  </div>
</div>
```

```js
$('#deleteCommentForm').on('submit', function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();

  let action = $(this).attr('action');

  axios.delete(action, []).then(function(response) {
    $(this).closest('div.comment').remove();
  });
});
```

Comment: You should store `this` in variable and use variable in callback instead

Comment: What are you expecting `this` to be within the `then` callback?

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan the form with id deleteCommentForm

Comment: In which case you need to store the reference to `this` in the outer scope, as @Mohammad suggested. Within the `then` callback, `this` will refer to the deferred object itself.

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan I tried it with the answer suggested by Praveen but doesn't work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You probably lost 'this' value in ajax callback function. You can just replace function with arrow function

```
axios.delete(action, []).then(response => {
    $(this).closest('div.comment').remove();
});
```

Comment: sure. brackets are optional if the argument is only one

Comment: didn't know this ;)

Comment: Note this arrow functions are completely unsupported in IE, so if you need legacy browser support, avoid this solution.

Answer (score 2):

The context of `this` changes in the `callback` function, so you need cache it.

```js
$('#deleteCommentForm').on('submit', function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  let $this = $(this);                      // <-- Add this code.
  let action = $this.attr('action');        // <-- Update here.

  axios.delete(action, []).then(function(response) {
    $this.closest('div.comment').remove();  // <-- Update here.
  });
});
```

So whenever a new function is started, the context always changes. To refer to the parent context, please define a variable in that scope.

Comment: @Michael Because you hasn't `.comment` in html. There is `.comments` or `.commment`

Comment: in you sollution perhaps it's better to store the JQuery element before the `.on()` call (outside of the block. so it's accessible from everywhere and `this` is not longer needed

Comment: @Michael My solution works better just in case, when ES6 arrow functions aren't supported by other browsers.

Answer (score 0):

the scope of this in your ajax response is not what you are awaiting

```
$('#deleteCommentForm').on('submit', function(e) {
  // stop all bubbling of the event
  e.preventDefault();
  e.stopPropagination();
  e.stopImmediatePropagation();

  let action = $(this).attr('action');

  // first way - using lamda function decoration does not change your scope on this
  axios.delete(action, []).then((response) => {
    $(this).closest('div.comment').remove();
  });

  // second Way -- store this to an accessable variable
  let element = this; 
  axios.delete(action, []).then(function(response) {
    $(element).closest('div.comment').remove();
  });

});
```